# Bathroom sink drain leak from under concrete floor

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

There is a bathroom on the lowest floor of the house built on concrete floor. When waste water goes down the sink into the pvc drain pipe, this waste water leaks out from under the concrete floor. I suspect that there is a pipe break under the concrete floor.

I suspect that the waste drain pipe of the sink goes under the floor and is connected to the drain pipe of the toilet on the right. When the toilet flushes, there is NO leak. The leak only occurs from the drain pipe of the sink.

What can be done to fix the leak? Is it necessary to break up the concrete floor? Because of the proximity to the toilet, is there a risk to accidentally damage the drain pipe under the toilet by breaking up the concrete?

[image]

Comment: How did you confirm it is actually from the pipe? Did you test by flushing colored dye down the system?

Comment: Is the "Bathroom sink Drain" at the cutout dry?

Comment: @nelson The bathroom sink drain at the cutout is not dry. When I add water to the bathroom sink drain opening on the left. Water comes gushing out at the indicated arrow.

Comment: It's just super odd that you use the word "gushing" when describing water going up against gravity. 
Anyways, if you're confident that it really is from the pipe, then fixing it would require smashing the concrete. That's why I asked how you confirmed it.